# Sorting python tuples contain non-comparable elements

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

When trying to compare dictionaries, python raises a TypeError:

`{"a" : "b"} < {"a" : "b"} # TypeError`

When trying to compare tuples, python does it elementwise:

`(1, 2) > (1, 1) # True`

Therefore, I expected that comparing tuples containing dictionaries would result in a TypeError if the elements preceding the dictionaries were equal because it would then be forced to compare the dictionaries, which would raise a TypeError. This is not the case:

`(3, {"a" : "b"}) < (3, {"a" : "b"})  # False, no TypeError`

I've read through the documentation I could find regarding Python sorting and did not see anything documenting this behavior. Can I rely on this behavior staying the same in future versions?

Comment: @DaniMesejo but `(3, {"a" : "b"}) < (3, {"c" : "d"})` does throw an error.

Comment: @Bobby `(3, {"a" : "b"}) < (3, {"a" : "b"})  # False, no TypeError` throws an error. 
`>>> (3, {"a" : "b"}) < (3, {"c" : "d"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Lexicographical comparison between built-in collections works as
> follows:
>
> For two collections to compare equal, they must be of the same type,
> have the same length, and each pair of corresponding elements must
> compare equal (for example, [1,2] == (1,2) is false because the type
> is not the same).
>
> Collections that support order comparison **are ordered the same as
> their first unequal elements** (for example, [1,2,x] <= [1,2,y] has the
> same value as x <= y). If a corresponding element does not exist, the
> shorter collection is ordered first (for example, [1,2] < [1,2,3] is
> true).

So the first thing that the tuple comparison will do is to find the unequal elements, as there are not unequal elements in your tuple the result is `False`, and there is no need to call the code for `<`.

This is further confirmed by looking at the implementation of the [comparison of tuples](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4903afd4debbbd71dc49a2c8fefa74a3b6c6832/Objects/tupleobject.c#L727):

```
for (i = 0; i < vlen && i < wlen; i++) {
    int k = PyObject_RichCompareBool(vt->ob_item[i],
                                     wt->ob_item[i], Py_EQ);
    if (k < 0)
        return NULL;
    if (!k)
        break;
}

if (i >= vlen || i >= wlen) {
    /* No more items to compare -- compare sizes */
    Py_RETURN_RICHCOMPARE(vlen, wlen, op);
}
```

The for loop in the code above tries to find the first unequal elements and if not found delegates the comparison to the size of the tuples.